# Facebook API dialog page showing error in second time and after that

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share my app details.I just done as same given in facebook tutorial.When user loggen in and dialog page appears and i posted my msg.and it worked fine for first time only.when user tapped a button to share again,the dialog appears and showing error page

`"Error occurred with 'Your_APP_NAME'.please try again later."`

I followed the tutorial in the facebook link below here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Here it is my code.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];

 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
            facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
            facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        }
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}else{
[self postWall];
}
// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self postWall];
}
-(void)postWall{

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   kAppId,@"app_id",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/",@"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg",@"picture",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs",@"name",
                                   @"Reference Documentation",@"caption",
                                   @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.",@"description",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",@"message",
                                   nil];

    [[self facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

I do all this code in my viewcontroller file(Not in app delegate).I want to open facebook only when i press the button..So i put these codings in my buttonpressed method.

Comment: please post some code, there is not enough detail

Comment: @Hanon I checked the flow of facebook API..I think i m getting error in shouldStartLoadWithRequest: in FBDialog file..In that code is checking URL scheme 'If loop' is not passing as 'fbconnect',instead it passes like as 'https'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with removing

```
kAppId,@"app_id"
```

from your `NSMutableDictionary params`

Comment: Thanks A lot yar!!...Thank you So much....Its working..Finally I made it Working..But I have a doubt?If that is only a problem then y facebook itself gave such tutorial with appId in params???