# facebook login from new fbconnect

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I want to implement facebook login in my iphone application using the latest sdk by facebook but I am not able to find anything simple. Hackbook is there but it is quite complex. Can some one help me by pointing to any tutorial that helps in that. I could not find any tutorial for new sdk.

Pankaj

Comment: did you take a look in the facebook docs? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Comment: use @Binyamin Sharet link to understand how to do facebook connectivity and check out this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9238700/1083859  for any doubts in facebook.

Comment: is it possible to open login dialog for login in facebook rather than, login from safari in Hackbook application for iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facebook offers a tutorial on this themselves, check out this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

providing code, screenshots etc =)

(btw: first hit on google ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial using graph API

> http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api

It has sample project with it explaining how to pull data from and posting data to facebook.